# Parallel running of two visual studio C++ program

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have two projects; one in WINDOWS visual Studio C++ and the other one in CONSOLE visual Studio C++. the second one is my main program that use some information of the first program. both of these programs get information from external devices real time. How can I link these two programs and run them parallel?
I 'v been searched but I can not find anything that link windows and console forms!!

Comment: what do you mean with link? Do you just want to run them both from VS? Then you need `Solution Properties->Startup Project`, and select Multiple Startup Project

Comment: Do you mean interprocess communication?